# How do I put on hold a message queue

Tags: asynchronous, activemq-classic, message, subscriber

Simplified:
I have a queue in activemq. When a certain message is read from the queue, I want to lock the queue until that process ends working on the received message.

Elaborate explanation:
I have a system with large amount of users. Each time a user changes his state in the system (profile, role, access, ownership of an asset etc), I need to also update a third party server with those changes.
That third party is separate from us and the api they expose to me allows me to update only one user at a time and takes about a second.
I am using ActiveMQ to detach the main update process from updating the third party system.

Once a night I get a feed file which might contain thousands of user changes. Since this is a critical task, and updating the third party is not so time sensitive, and since updating the third party might require to read from same table the main process is bulk updating, I need to lock the queue.
Meaning, I want activeMQ to get the messages for each user I changed in the main process, but I also want ActiveMQ to hold on to those messages until the main process is done.

Any built in mechanism in ActiveMQ to do so?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a system that is [update process] -AMQ-> [adapter] -> [3rd party API], and you don't want the adapter to run until you the update process has fed all the messages in?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you read a message at a time per consumer.

You typically have a listener that looks like this:

```
void onMessage( Message message ) {

     // .. 
     updateExternalAPI(); // Sync. call to external API

 }
```

So when your `onMessage` method ends, the message is committed and that consumer will proceed with the next message. So, only a single message will be processed at a time - IF there is only one consumer.

If you have only one node of your server application, this is easy - simply configure it to use only a single consumer. It's a bit different in different frameworks/client libraries.

If you cannot do this and/or have multiple nodes - ActiveMQ offers a solution. Add `?consumer.exclusive=true` to your queue in the client to force ActiveMQ to choose a single consumer to dispatch messages to.

Example `UPDATE.USER.INFO?consumer.exclusive=true`.

Comment: There is one consumer. But what he wan is when an arbitrary process is running, the ActiveMQ will not release anymore messages it has in its queue. He want the ActiveMQ to hold on to those messages until AMQ gets the "green light"

Comment: That is correct. I have implemented my own lock solution, but was wondering if there is a way to signal AMQ to lockdown a single topic/queue